# Searching in an array of structs in C

Tags: c

What is the best way to search through an array of structs containing both strings and integers in C programming?

An axamle of the array of structs:

```
struct person {
    int age;
    int length;
    char fname[20];
    char lname[20];
};
Typedef struct person Person

int main()
{
    Person personarray[100];
}
```

Comment: Searching... by what? Age? Name? - Is the array sorted or unsorted? What have you tried?

Comment: Old fashioned `for` loop. For example, to search `fname`: `for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++) ... check personarray[i].fname for what you want, etc`

Comment: use `bsearch` if elements are sorted.

Comment: You will be able to chose if you want to search by name or by ange. if you search for example "ry" then you should get the result from all structs that contain ry in the name. For example "Ryan"

Answer (score 0):

One commenter pointed out you can use [bsearch](http://linux.die.net/man/3/bsearch).
But a simple loop based coding example to answer your question about how to walk the array follows.

```
#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE 100
#define NAME_BOB "Bob"

struct person {
    int age;
    int length;
    char fname[20];
    char lname[20];
};

typedef struct person Person;

int main()
{
    Person people[MAX_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE];
    for (int i; i < sizeof (people) / sizeof (struct people); i++) {
         Person *person = &people[i];
         if (person->age == 21) {
             println("%s %s can legally drink\n", 
                   person->fname,  person->lname);
         }
         if (strncmp(person->fname, NAME_BOB, sizeof (NAME_BOB)) == 0) {
             println("Bob is %d years old\n", 
                   person->age);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better just to use `MAX_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE` instead of the `sizeof () / sizeof()` that will be calculated on each iteration of the loop?

Comment: sizeof() is a compile-time operator, so it it isn't calculated each loop.